# How to make a function that calculate elements in list?

Tags: python

I'm doing my heart game programming but I'm confused on how to calculate all the scores in each card 
This is the card that has value, other cards have 0 value

```
>>> card_value ={"QS":13,"2H":1,"3H":1,"4H":1,"5H":1,"6H":1,"7H":1,"8H":1,"9H":1,"0H":1,"JH":1,"QH":1,"KH":1,"AH":1,"0D": -10}
```

but if all the sub lists in a set of lists contain a heart then the score will be -26 and if all the sub lists in a set of lists contain a heart and 10 Diamonds("0D") then the score will be -36

*example*

```
>>> list1 = [['QD', '7D', '5H', '0D'], ['7C', '6D', '2H', 'KS'], ['8S', '3D', '9C', 'KD'], ['4D', '9D', 'KH', '4C'],['7S', 'JH', '4H', 'QC'], ['2S', 'KC', 'AD', 'AC'], ['JD', '8D', 'QS', '6H'], ['AH', '9H', '9S', '6S'],['5S', '0S', 'JC', '2D'],['5D', '8H', '0C', '7H'], ['JS', '6C', '2C', 'AS'], ['3S', '4S', '5C', '0H'], ['3C', 'QH', '3H', '8C']]
```

The output from this will be -36

```
>>> list2 = ["5C","QS","JH"]
```

The output from this will be 14

this is what I have tried so far:

```
def score(list,score=0):
    for cards in list:
        if cards in card_value.keys():
            score += card_value[cards]    
        if cards == "H":
            score = -36
        if cards == "H" or "0D":
            score = -26
   return score
```

Comment: I think Marcin means: what have you used to process the lists and dictionaries into the "total" values that you describe?  Like my answer below does.

Comment: how can scores be "H"? and how can score be "H" or "0D" if it is a score ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `total` to zero in both cases then do something like

```
for i in list2: total=total+card_value.get(i,0)

for l in list1:
   for i in l:
    total=total+card_value.get(i,0)
```

The total back from list1 is 16 not -36 with this technique bu I think you must get the idea

edit:
now with this "if all the cards in a list have all hearts then the score will be -26" business.  I am assuming from your comments below that this actually means "if all the sub lists in a set of lists contain at least one heart then the score will be -26"

```
for l in list1:
   for i in l:
    total=total+card_value.get(i,0)
    if i[0] == 'H':   # first character of card string is a H- so it's a heart
      heart_counter = heart_counter + 1
if heart_counter == len(list1):
   total = total - 26
```

Comment: no, the answer suppose to be -36 since I'm doing a different version of Heart. And in list1 there is one heart in each list and there is also 10 diamonds. So it must be -36 not 16.

Comment: "if all the cards in a list have all hearts then the score will be -26" is not the same as "if all the sub lists in a set of lists contain a heart then the score will be -26", so you can see why I was confused

Comment: @Vorspring ah yeah my bad! Sorry, my english is not that good, but i really tried to explain it and i really want to learn coding too. So i can be as good as u guys! :)